# UIView not responding after dismissing UIAlertview in iOS 7 SDK

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios7, uialertview

I have one view controller added as subview in some other view controller and in that sub view controller I am presenting a UIAlertview. After dismissing that alert view the view become unresponsive to touch. It becomes active again when I minimize the application and launch it again.

Any thoughts..

Here is code that I am using,
First I added child view controller as subview in my main view controller inside a uiscrollview.

```
SharedViewController *sharedVC = [[SharedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SharedViewController" bundle:nil];
[sharedVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(2048, 0, 1024, 545)];
sharedVC.delagate = self;
[mainScrollView addSubview:sharedVC.view];
```

And in SharedViewController I have a button tapping on which I do this,

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"No File selected. Please select some of them and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
```

After presenting the alertview and atpping OK button the view becomes unresponsive unless I minimize the app and open it again.

Comment: I think you need to add more details to this. Maybe show some of your code. Nobody has posted any answers for this because they don't have enough details to formulate one.

Comment: Also you mention that you're adding a view controller as a subview of another view controller. Are you doing proper UIViewController containment?

Comment: X coordinate of your view is out of bounds (x = 2048)

Comment: its in scroll view so no issue with x-coordinate bounds

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem recently. Hopefully your problem is solved. My answer may help others. Do not add any view or present any view or remove any view or even push after the alert show code. The following was my code, and I was facing the same problem:

```
UIAlertView *errorLert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro" message:@"Operation could not be performed at this time, please try again later" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                        [errorLert show];
[customView removeFromSuperView];
```

then I just removed my last line and shifted before the alert and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

after work of sub view controller is done you have to add following line..

I am not sure but may you get help..

```
    [sharedVC removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sharedVC.view.superview==Nil) {
        CGRect frame = mainScrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        sharedVC.view.frame = frame;
        [mainScrollView addSubview:sharedVC.view];
    }
```